# What is the best way to only display some of the html elements in the ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to use an ng-if inside an ng-repeat (as described in this question):
However, I want to display a row in a table if and only if the if condition holds. In the answers to the question above, you will get empty div tags where the if condition does not hold. This does not cause much of a problem with divs, but when doing the same with tables, you do not want to have div (or span) tags inbetween tr tags.

Is there another tag or directive that I could use?

Comment: I went for Sander Elias's answer because this mixes an if statement in with a foreach directive, whilst keeping the DOM simple (no unwanted hidden elements) and is also a lot faster. In my case, the statements looked something like:
    <tr ng-repeat="control in controls | filter: controlName | filter:{riskParentId :  risk.riskId}:true ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better idea is to use a (custom) filter.
That way, only the needed rows are generated, in stead of hiding/removing existing ones.

I just made [a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTv3tHimywEQZLpxA1Ee?p=preview) for another question, that showed how to use a filter:

the relevant line is this one:

```
<tr ng-repeat='item in appVm.users |filter:test'>
```

you can use a object directly in your code like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat='item in appVm.users |filter:{age:32}'>
```

If you put that line in the sample I linked in, you can see how that would work out!

Does this help you?

Comment: I feel that this may get complicated on my page as I already have custom filters on the page and there are lots of nested tables. I like the answer though and will look into it further.

Comment: @Sam, You can specify the filter directly in your template too. That way you don't need an extra property on your scope/controller.  Ill update the answer a bit to show you how!

Comment: Sounds neat. I am currently using Asterius' answer. I wasn't able to use angular-js to set the value attribute for the filter. I will also be interested to see how it compares for performance.

Comment: @Sam, My guess, the filter solution will be a lot faster. There will be less DOM, and less DOM manipulation.

Comment: I don't think that I am able to do this in my solution, because I need access to the object in the loop in the if statement. 
For example, I'm looping through 'coreDuty in coreDuties' which is within a loop for 'department in departments'. I then want to check that the statement 'coreDuty.departmentParentId == department.departmentId' holds. If I put this as an inline filter as part of my ng-repeat directive, then I do not yet have access to the coreDuty object. 
Whereas, if i use ng-show, then this has access to the coreDuty object

Comment: @Sam, you can use an expression for the filter, so you can indeed put the expression 'coreDuty.departmentParentId == department.departmentId' in there. I don't have the time now to build you a sample plunk, sorry about that.

Comment: I was not debating whether or not you can put an expression in the filter. I tested it with expressions and it worked. I did try the statement above and it was not successful - it seems that the coreDuty object is not set when using an inline filter. I believe that the statement would hold true, if I wrote 'coreDuty.departmentParentId == null' - I will test this later.

Comment: @Sam, in your case you need to format your expression a bit different. it should look like this:
`filter:{departmentParentId :department.departmentId}:true`
That will make sure it's an exact match.

Comment: I did some performance testing and after changing all the ng-show directives to filters instead, the page loads in about 0.4 seconds instead of about 2.5 seconds. Also the DOM is a lot neater now! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide these elements, you can consider using ng-show instead of ng-if.
Maybe you can also add the ng-show in the ng-if tag to hide it when empty.

Now, if you do not want to render the content at all, I think the only solution is to remove these elements from your collection in your controller

Comment: Thanks. This works well be using an ng-show directive beside the ng-repeat directive and ignoring the ng-if directive.
I am yet to fully test Sander's answer, but will mark this as used if that one does not prove favorable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-show.its works for show and hide tags.if you don't want to angular compile inside the tag you can use ng-if.